# Forwarding ref with hoc styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to use forwardRef with this component but couldn't make it work. Here's the component

```
import { StyledInput, StyledSecondaryInput } from './style'

const handleWrapping = (Component, props) => {
  const { ...rest } = props

  return <Component {...rest} />
}

export const Input = (props) => handleWrapping(StyledInput, props)

export const SecondaryInput = (props) =>
  handleWrapping(StyledSecondaryInput, props)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of the function will be the ref, if it's wrapped in [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

```
import { StyledInput, StyledSecondaryInput } from "./style";
import { forwardRef } from "react";

const handleWrapping = (Component, props) => {
  const { forwardedRef, ...rest } = props;

  return <Component {...rest} ref={forwardedRef} />;
};

export const Input = forwardRef((props, ref) =>
  handleWrapping(StyledInput, { forwardedRef: ref, ...props })
);

export const SecondaryInput = forwardRef((props, ref) =>
  handleWrapping(StyledSecondaryInput, { forwardedRef: ref, ...props })
);
```